# use saltstack state.sls to install mysql but not return

Tags: salt-stack

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

my saltstack file code in github
[saltstack file](https://github.com/fanne/salt)

install mysql salt code:

```
[root@salt_master srv]# cat salt/base/lnmp_yum/mysql/mysql_install.sls 
repo_init:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-{{pillar['mysql_version']}}.repo
    - source: salt://lnmp_yum/mysql/files/mysql-{{pillar['mysql_version']}}.repo
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644

mysql_install:
  pkg.installed:
    - names:
      - mysql
      - mysql-server
      - mysql-devel
    - require:
      - file: repo_init    

  service.running:
    - name: mysqld
    - enable: True
```

after run cmd:

```
salt 'lnmp_base' state.sls lnmp_yum.mysql.mysql_install -l debug
```

always print log:

```
[DEBUG   ] Checking whether jid 20170526144936867490 is still running
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'salt_master_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] Passing on saltutil error. This may be an error in saltclient. 'retcode'
[DEBUG   ] Checking whether jid 20170526144936867490 is still running
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'salt_master_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] Passing on saltutil error. This may be an error in saltclient. 'retcode'
[DEBUG   ] Checking whether jid 20170526144936867490 is still running
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'salt_master_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] Passing on saltutil error. This may be an error in saltclient. 'retcode'
```

when i look salt node server, mysql already installed and start,but salt master server always print log, no exit.

I searched for days, but I could not solve it.

the same question when i install jboss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts  occur to me:

1. I think mysql has a basic configuration ncurses gui that requires user input to configure (Set default password etc).  If I remember that correctly then your salt state is still running and waiting for a human to type at the screen.  You can fix this by feeding it an answer/config file.
   Stolen shamelesly from another post:

> ```
> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
> sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.6
> ```

2. The other is that it may simply take longer than your salt timeout default for a task.  That can be configured in salt at the salt cmd line with -t or the config file (forget which setting)